# Appending results from infinite scroll call to results displayed by default in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function making a $http call and displaying some results. After this particular function, I added another function that will make further calls upon the scroll event (using the ng-Infinite-Scroll module).

My problem is that I can't seem to be able to append the results from the second and following calls to the results displayed by the default call.

Here's my code.

```
$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;
    });
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=12').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2.releases;
  });  

  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.artist;
  }, function() {
    var pos = $scope.artist.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(', the');
    if (pos != -1) {
      $scope.artist.name = 'The ' + $scope.artist.name.slice(0, pos);
    }
  });

  var _page = 1;
  $scope.releases = [];
  $scope.loadDetails = function() {
      _page++;
      console.log(_page);
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=' + _page + '&per_page=12').then(function(data2) {
          $scope.releases = data2.releases;
      });
  };    

  $scope.clicked = true;
  $scope.sliding = true;
}
```

Where the following function will call the first page and 12 items:

```
$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=12').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2.releases;
});
```

Later on, I trigger the loadDetails function and it'll make the calls correctly (page 2, 3, and so on), and update the $scope.releases, but so far when this happens, instead of displaying the new results, it disappears all completely once the loadDetails function is called.

```
  var _page = 1;
  $scope.releases = [];
  $scope.loadDetails = function() {
      _page++;
      console.log(_page);
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=' + _page + '&per_page=12').then(function(data2) {
          $scope.releases = data2.releases;
      });
  };
```

I assume that instead of redefining $scope.releases, I have to append the results from the second and following calls to it, but I can't see how i'd do this.

Any hints?

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hHboAx1Q6TCG7Vqi2zjq?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think primarily the problem is that `id` was missing from loadDetails signature, and `.then` wasn't waiting for `$http.get` to return the releases.  I substituted `.success`, and it works.

Here is an update of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gSwRNUn9mBvhWDtIaEzD

```
$scope.getDetails = function(id) {
  $scope._page = 1;
  $scope.releases = [];

  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.artist = data;
  });
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=12').
  success(function(data2) {
    $scope.releases = data2.releases;
  });


  $scope.clicked = true;
  $scope.sliding = true;
};

$scope.loadDetails = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  if (!angular.isUndefined(id)) {
    $scope._page++;
    console.log($scope._page);
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=' + $scope._page + '&per_page=12').
    success(function(data2) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data2.releases.length; i++) {
        $scope.releases.push(data2.releases[i]);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I'm just using a loop and .push to append to the array.